# KSS styleguide generator in PHP?

Tags: php, css, knyle-style-sheet

I like [KSS](http://warpspire.com/kss/) (Knyle Style Sheets). I'm aware of the original [styleguide generator](https://github.com/kneath/kss)  written in Ruby and I've seen [a port to Node](https://github.com/hughsk/kss-node/) and a [Rails engine](https://github.com/dewski/kss-rails).

I could not find any other implementations but I would like to know,
**is there an implementation of the KSS styleguide generator in PHP?**

<sup>(Or, as a side note, any other language?)</sup>

**Edit**: As [janiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/475151/janiv) mentions in the comments, there *is* a PHP implementation [available on github](https://github.com/kss-php/kss-php).

Comment: I guess that means "no"then.

Comment: I was looking for the same thing and ended up converting it to php myself. You can check it out at https://github.com/scaninc/kss-php

Comment: @janiv I was planning on doing the same but hadn't gotten around to it yet. Consider your code starred and forked! :-)

Comment: The kss-php project has moved to https://github.com/kss-php/kss-php